# Normally distributed eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of $n\times n$ (growing size) random matrices. Suppose also that

$$\lambda_1(X'_nX_n)\overset{p}{\to} 0 \hspace{1cm} \text{as} \hspace{1cm} n\to \infty$$

where $\lambda_1$ denotes the largest eigenvalue and $\overset{p}{\to}$ denotes convergence in probability. Am interested in the elements in the $n\times 1$ eigenvector $Q$, say corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $X'_nX_n$.

Can I show these elements to be normally distributed as $n\to \infty$?

Simulations seem to indicated that this is the case. For example if we take $X_n:=\frac{1}{n}Y_n$ where the elements of $Y_n$ are iid with finite variances.

Thanks a lot for your help.